# JavaScript - Using Math.random on a for loop to count down

Tags: javascript

So I have this game where you click a button and your target takes damage. The loop I'm trying to do is suppose to hit 45-450 damage to a target with 990 hitpoints.

I'm asking if there is a way to use Math.random on a loop like this? Is it better to do with another method or is my loop completely wrong.

```
for (var hp = 990; hp >= 0; hp - Math.floor((Math.random() * 450) + 45)) {
}
```

Comment: the final hp is not an assignment. did you mean `hp -= Math.floor((Math.random() * 450) + 45` ? this will reduce the health until it is < 0, and so loop a certain number of times.

Answer (score 0):

It is valid if you use hp -= ... assignment, not just h - ...

```js
var hp = 990;
for (hp = 990; hp >= 0; hp -= Math.floor((Math.random() * 450) + 45)) {
  console.log("hp:", hp);
}
console.log("no more hp");
```